# plsql subtract columns in a same table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a simple student table.

```
name  | amount | vdate
Josh  | 15     | 01.01.2020
Steve | 25     | 05.04.2008
Josh  | 40     | 01.01.2022
```

What I want to do is subtract Josh value from each other.

I wrote this query but it is not working

```
   select name , sum(b.amount-a.amount) diff from  
     select name,amount from student a where name = 'Josh' and vdate='01.01.2020'
     union all
     select name,amount from student b where name = 'Josh' and vdate = '01.01.2022')
   group by name
```

Expected Result is:

```
name | diff
Josh | 25
Steve| 25
```

Comment: How to you decide if you subtract Josh's `15` from Josh's `40` or vice-versa?

Comment: Would the duplicate names always appear in pairs?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add vdate column.I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code,

```
    select 
    fname,
    abs(sum(amount2)) amount
from
(
WITH
student(fname,amount,vdate) AS (
            SELECT 'Josh' ,15, to_date('01102017','ddmmyyyy')  from dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Steve',25,  to_date('01102017','ddmmyyyy') from dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Josh' ,40   ,to_date('01102019','ddmmyyyy')from dual
)


select 
    h.fname,
    h.amount,
    decode((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fname order by vdate desc)),1,amount,amount* -1) amount2

    from student h
)
group by 
    fname
    ;
```

I assume that you get the greater amount value of the person and substract other values, you can select the bigger date instead by modifying the order by clause in the partition window i. e.

```
decode((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fname order by vdate desc)),1,amount,amount * -1) amount2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I don't know what sense it makes ...):
Count the number of rows found until now per `fname` ("name" is a reserved word and I don't use it). And if the row number obtained this way is odd, then use the negative amount, else the positive amount.
Finally, run a sum over these positive/negative rows.

```
WITH
indata(fname,amount) AS (
            SELECT 'Josh' ,15 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Steve',25
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Josh' ,40 
)
,
alternate AS (
  SELECT
    fname
  , CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fname) % 2 
      WHEN 1 THEN amount * -1 -- when odd then negative
      ELSE        amount      -- else positive
    END  AS amount
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  fname
, ABS(SUM(amount)) AS amount -- absolute value
FROM alternate
GROUP BY fname;
-- out  fname | amount 
-- out -------+--------
-- out  Josh  |     25
-- out  Steve |     25
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Actually I always subtract bigger date from lower date.

Comment: So what would happen  if there more than 2 rows for  a given name: Foe example in addition to the current data the following row existed: `Josh | 30 |  01.01.2021`?  Would always subtracting bigger date from the lower would be `40-30-15=-5` or `40-(30-15)=15`, or something else?  You also need to define bigger vs lower date. It would seem 01.01.2022 is bigger than  01.01.2020 but then the result should be -25.  Please update the question; do not just make a comment.